# Godot4 fullscreen settings issue

Tags: fullscreen, godot4

I tried to make a project be in fullscreen in godot4. These are my settings:
[image]

and this is my main scene:
[image]

as you can see, I want the shape to be in the middle of the screen. But when I play the game, this happens:[image]
why is the picture not in the center?

and why when I click on the green button (the resize button) it resizes and works perfectly fine. How do I fix this? I want it to work fine in fullscreen.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Camera2D` to the scene and set its `current` property to `true`, then what you see in the game is what the `Camera2D` "sees".